# retrofit2 return observable with 1 object for each onNext

Tags: android, gson, retrofit2, rx-android

I've started using retrofit2, rxjava and GSON and I was wondering something. Currently I have something like this:

```
@GET("roster/byid/{userId}")
    Observable<List<Contact>> roster(@Path("userId") int userId);
```

If a contact would contain a lot of information or there are a lot of contacts in the roster it would use a lot of memory.
Is it possible to get an observable back where you get every contact in onNext one-by-one? So I can process it, save it to the database and move on to the next contact? I know gson supports streaming but I don't know how to use it in combination with retrofit2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can flatMap to another Observable and then use Observable.from(List) (see http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/from.html) which emit onNext for each value in the list. Is that what you were looking for?

```
    final List<String> listString = new ArrayList<>();
    listString.add("AAAA");
    listString.add("BBBB");
    listString.add("CCCC");
    Observable.just(listString)
            .flatMap(new Func1<List<String>, Observable<String>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<String> call(List<String> strings) {
                    Log.d("FLAT MAP", "call: " + strings);
                    return Observable.from(strings);
                }
            })
            .map(new Func1<String, String>() {
                @Override
                public String call(String s) {
                    Log.d("MAP", "call: " + s);
                    return s;
                }
            })
            .subscribe(new Action1<String>() {
                @Override
                public void call(String s) {
                    Log.d("SUBSCRIBER", "call: " + s);
                }
            });
```

LOGS OUTPUT

```
FLAT MAP: call: [AAAA, BBBB, CCCC]
MAP: call: AAAA
SUBSCRIBER: call: AAAA
MAP: call: BBBB
SUBSCRIBER: call: BBBB
MAP: call: CCCC
SUBSCRIBER: call: CCCC
```